# RxJava repeatWhen doesn't called again in Mockito

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, mockito, rx-java

I am writing a testing code using Mockito.
I am using RxJava and Retrofit to get the resource from the server.

mockRestService.get(id) method returns Observable.
First, the request call returns an item with the status of "not ready".
So I should use the Rx operator "repeatWhen()".
After some retry, the server sends an item with the status of "complete".

Below is my Presenter code.

```
val getItem = restService.getItem(id)
                .repeatWhen { it.delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) }
                .takeUntil { it.status == "complete" }
```

And below is my testing code.
To mimic server behaviour, I wrote below the testing code.

```
@Test
fun printJobTest_one_job_normal_case() {

    val notReadyItem = Item(status = "not ready")
    val completeItem = Item(status = "complete")

    Mockito.`when`(mockRestService.getItem(id))
        .thenReturn(Observable.just(notReadyItem)) // First 2 response is "not ready" status
        .thenReturn(Observable.just(notReadyItem))
        .thenReturn(Observable.just(completeItem)) // Third response is "complete" status

    // verify
}
```

To mimic the server behaviour, I used chained "thenReturn()" method.
But only always the item which's status is "not ready" occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I... found the solution.
It's easy...
Just below code works fine.

```
@Test
fun printJobTest_one_job_normal_case() {

    val notReadyItem = Item(status = "not ready")
    val completeItem = Item(status = "complete")

    Mockito.`when`(mockRestService.getItem(id))
        .thenReturn(Observable.just(notReadyItem, notReadyItem, completeItem))

    // verify
}
```

I just removed the chained method "thenReturn", and moved the variables to the parameter of Observable.